# flutter tts no sound is playing

Tags: flutter

I want to convert text to audio using the tts package, I wrote the following methods and added the necessary code to the manifest file, but when I click the button, the sound does not play.

```
 IconButton(
        onPressed: () {
                 _speak(words.english!);
                       },
         icon: Icon(Icons.volume_up,
             color: Colors.white)),
```

---

```
final FlutterTts tts = FlutterTts();

Future _speak(String text) async {
    await tts.setLanguage("en-US");
    await tts.setPitch(1);
    await tts.setSpeechRate(0.8);
    await tts.speak(text);
  }
```

Comment: Does the device has downloaded the text to speech language?

Comment: I do not understand. Google speech app??

Comment: I am facing similar issue :(

Answer (score 1):

**You can solve the issue by simply adding a code given below in your AndroidManifest.xml File**

*CODE:-*

```
<queries>
    <intent>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.TTS_SERVICE" />
    </intent>
</queries>
```

**then re-build the app once to see the output.**